# Sprites in cocos2d-x not drawn to proportion

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Im trying to draw a Sprite, and when its get drawn it appears to be 2-3 times smaller than the actually image is.

```
    Sprite* sprite = Sprite::create("image.png");
sprite->setAnchorPoint(Point(0, 0));
addChild(sprite);
```

i do not call EGLView::setDesignResolutionSize() nor do i call Director::setContentScaleFactor().

Im testing on a Kindle fire (2.3.3) if it helps, and using cocos2d-x 3.0 alpha.

Comment: It may appear smaller if you are looking at it at devices with different pixel density. Could you try setting `setContentScaleFactor(1.0f);` explicitly?

Comment: I tryed that but EGLView sets scaleX and scaleY to 1.0f by default. Idk how to scale based on pixel density.